# When to use Proxy in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, proxy, retrofit

I am not understanding when and how to use **Proxy** in **Retrofit Android**. What is the use-case of it? I am not finding any example related to this.

Comment: May I ask what triggered your question? `Proxy` is an [implementation detail](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/576f23dae73814b23787322d8f663c4421af8939/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java#L142-L163) of Retrofit - it's how the library delegates interface calls to actual behavior. It's also used in [BehaviorDelegate](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/576f23dae73814b23787322d8f663c4421af8939/retrofit-mock/src/main/java/retrofit2/mock/BehaviorDelegate.java#L62-L87) in `retrofit-mock` artifact.

Comment: @Alex Krupa, I need to give a PPT on that. But before giving a Presentation I need to understand this. I am not getting proper examples of Android applications using Proxy

Comment: Another example is [Scarlet](https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/blob/master/scarlet/src/main/java/com/tinder/scarlet/Scarlet.kt#L110-L114), which is pretty much "Retrofit but for WebSockets".  I'd say diving into both libraries' sources would be great for presentation purposes. Also, don't forget about the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). :)